# Simple WMS server

Tags: python, wms, php, mysql, server

Is there a way to implement a WMS server using only php or python cgi and mysql? I can't use geoserver or mapserver and postgres and any other software as they are not provided by the administrator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check out https://github.com/klokantech/tileserver-php/ might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 5):

You could use TileMill to make tiles as MBTiles: https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/

Then use something like python-mbtiles to serve it up: https://github.com/perrygeo/python-mbtiles.

Comment: Just a quick clarification: This won't really be a WMS service. It's a tileset that can be accessed as a XYZLayer; However, it is probably OP's only option.

Comment: Is  this a cgi service cause I don't have access to shell.

Comment: @neogeomat, take a look at the docs for python-mbtiles. You can do either. Use TileMill to make (pre-render) tiles. Then use the python script to make a folder full of tiles that can be grabbed using a standard format (url/x/y/z or whatever) or the script can read straight from the SQLite database that TileMill generates. You could also use MapBox to host it all for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you have tiled map in MBTiles format, you can serve them using ordinary PHP script. All you need is php-sqlite module, which should be included by default. You can try this: [mbtiles-php](https://github.com/infostreams/mbtiles-php/) - I'm using similar script in production. With some kind of URL-routing library, you can even simulate standard TMS.

Actually, you also can write your own WMS implementation using PHP or Python and MySQL database as a backend, but the task is tedious, and it is likely that you will get banned for putting too much load on the server. Bear in mind that WMS is very resource-hungry service.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try [Mapnik's OGCServer](https://github.com/mapnik/OGCServer) which is apparently a pure python wms server